# App para de responder quando executa onStartCommand

Tags: android, android-service

Eu chamo o service no `onPause()` da minha activity e assim que saio do app, ele para de responder depois de um tempo. Pelo que pesquisei pode ser que os processos sejam muito pesados para serem executados em segundo plano. Eu preciso verificar o horário pra saber se está na hora de enviar  a notificação.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (inicio != null) {
            ok = trataData(d2,d3);
            horaNotificacao.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,this.intervalo);
            while (ok == true){
                try {
                    agora = new Date();
                    if(agora.equals(horaNotificacao.getTime())){
                        gerarNotificacao();
                        horaNotificacao.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,this.intervalo);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ok = trataData(d2,d3);
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

trataData:

```
   public boolean trataData(Date d2, Date d3) {
        boolean ok = false;
        Date d1 = new Date();
        if (d1.before(d2) && d1.after(d3)){
            ok = true;
        }
        return ok;
    }
```

Acho q o problema ta nesse laço do ok, mas n vejo outra forma de fazer a verificação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Service` não é uma `Thread` separada, isso significa que ele roda na sua **Main Thread** fazendo assim com que sua aplicação pare de responder.

Para resolver o problema você precisa executar sua rotina dentro de uma nova `Thread`.

Ficaria desse jeito:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          // Coloque sua rotina aqui dentro
       }).start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Com isto, a sua rotina demorada será executada em uma nova `Thread`. Do jeito que está no seu código, ela é executada no `onPause()` até terminar, por isso que acontece o problema.

Não esqueça também de parar o serviço após terminar a execução da rotina.

---

**Veja mais nos links abaixo:**

[Android Service Example](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-service-example)

[Antipattern: freezing the UI with a Service and an IntentService](http://gmariotti.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/antipattern-freezing-ui-with-service.html)

Comment: Deu certooo! Obrigada de novo :D